# Promises within Promise.all not getting executed

Tags: javascript, promise

Could someone help me why the promise within the promise.all i.e ( suggestRC and suggestGL) are not getting called?  I would like to make sure the suggestRC and suggestGL are executed concurrently. That was the reason, I had written like this. extractIdeas is getting called but suggestRC and suggestGL are not getting called.

```
function suggestValues(editIdeaPanel) {

    Requests.deckreposvc({searchIdeas: {searchString: searchReq}})
        .then(extractIdeas)
        .then(Promise.all([suggestRC, suggestGL]))
        .catch(handleError);
}

function extractIdeas(searchRes) {
    return searchRes.searchIdeas.data;
}


function suggestRC(ideas) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              //do something 
        }
        resolve(ideas);
    });
}

function suggestGL(ideas) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(!editIdeaPanel.wdGLeaderCombo.propertyValue.uuid) {
           //do something
    }
        resolve(ideas);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* those two functions (add parentheses) in a *callback* that you pass to `then`:

```
.then(data => Promise.all([suggestRC(data), suggestGL(data)]))
```

Also, you will want *suggestValues* to `return` the promise:

```
return Requests.deckreposvc( //...etc
```